# ANTLR4 doesn't manage with left recursion properly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, antlr4

I'm trying to describe the grammar for logical expressions using ANTLR4. 
Surely, this grammar has direct left recursion, and as I've read ANTLR4 supports it.

```
grammar Logic;
@header {
package parser;
import expression.*;
}

expression returns [Expression value] : disjunction {$value = $disjunction.value;}
                                      | disjunction IMPLIES expression {$value = new Implication($disjunction.value, $expression.value);};

disjunction returns [Expression value] : conjunction {$value = $conjunction.value;}
                                       | disjunction OR conjunction {$value = new Disjunction($disjunction.value, $conjunction.value);};

conjunction returns [Expression value] : negation {$value = $negation.value;}
                                       | conjunction AND negation {$value = new Conjunction($conjunction.value, $negation.value);};

negation returns [Expression value] : variable {$value = $variable.value;}
                                    | NOT negation {$value = new Negation($negation.value);}
                                    | OB expression CB {$value = $expression.value;};

variable returns [Expression value] : VAR {$value = new Variable($VAR.text);};

IMPLIES : '->';
OR : '|';
AND : '&';
NOT : '!';
OB : '(';
CB : ')';
VAR : [A-Z]([0-9])*;
```

But when I'm running antlr to generate parser for my grammar, it gives some strange errors:

```
error(65): Logic.g4:5:125: unknown attribute value for rule disjunction in $disjunction.value
error(65): Logic.g4:5:125: unknown attribute value for rule conjunction in $conjunction.value
```

When I swap disjunction and conjunction in disjunction rule, making disjunction right-associative, it works, but this can cause some mistakes in my work.

As it might be important, I generate parsers using ANTLR4-plugin for Intellij Idea.

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referring to a `disjunction` in your code:

```
disjunction returns [Expression value]
 : conjunction {$value = $conjunction.value;}
 | disjunction OR conjunction {$value = new Disjunction($disjunction.value, $conjunction.value);}
 ;
```

ANTLR tries to get the `value` of the entire enclosing rule if you do `$disjunction` instead of the `disjunction` in `disjunction  OR ...`.

If you want to refer to `disjunction` in `disjunction  OR ...`, you need to label it before referencing it:

```
disjunction returns [Expression value]
 : c1=conjunction                  {$value = $c1.value;}
 | d=disjunction OR c2=conjunction {$value = new Disjunction($d.value, $c2.value);}
 ;
```

Here's a full working (tested) example:

```
grammar Logic;

@header {
  import expression.*;
}

expression returns [Expression value]
 : d1=disjunction                      {$value = $d1.value;}
 | d2=disjunction IMPLIES e=expression {$value = new Implication($d2.value, $e.value);}
 ;

disjunction returns [Expression value]
 : c1=conjunction                  {$value = $c1.value;}
 | d=disjunction OR c2=conjunction {$value = new Disjunction($d.value, $c2.value);}
 ;

conjunction returns [Expression value]
 : n1=negation                   {$value = $n1.value;}
 | c=conjunction AND n2=negation {$value = new Conjunction($c.value, $n2.value);}
 ;

negation returns [Expression value]
 : variable         {$value = $variable.value;}
 | NOT n=negation   {$value = new Negation($n.value);}
 | OB expression CB {$value = $expression.value;}
 ;

variable returns [Expression value]
 : VAR {$value = new Variable($VAR.text);}
 ;

IMPLIES : '->';
OR      : '|';
AND     : '&';
NOT     : '!';
OB      : '(';
CB      : ')';
VAR     : [A-Z]([0-9])*;
SPACE   : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. I don't have any problems with first rule, it works as expected. Those errors occur in disjunction-rule and conjunction-rule respectively.